# Bullet-Proof ACL using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, acl

I am new to AngularJS and trying to grasp the concept of implementing an access control layer so that some pages/menus will be hidden from certain users.

I usually implement ACL and all routes on the back-end (PHP/MySQL) but this project require me to do everything on the client side only.

We have a remote server that is in charge of authentication and upon successful login, will return an `is_admin` flag so that I know whether to display the additional info.

Although not likely, since Angular is also the rendering engine and is in charge of all the logic, I am afraid that users will be able to play with browser developer tools and/or other 3rd party tools and gain access to those areas (since all scripts & logic will be visible to them in the browser).

So if I do something like:

```
     if (user.is_admin === true) 
        {
            //display the additional admin data...
        }
```

A user can potentially set `user.is_admin = true` in the browser tools and gain access.

With server side rendering such as PHP, the user will never be able to even know about these hidden areas. i.e

```
    <?php 
       if ($user->is_admin === true) {...}//user will never ever see that or be able to modify $user properties
    ?>
```

Of course that the server will keep on authenticating every request so this exploit will only allow limited access, but still seems like a non secure way of hiding sections from certain users.

Am I missing something in Angular or is there a better way of doing it so that it's bullet-proof for client side hacks?

Comment: Well - the trouble is you're doing client side auth, so could a user change the flag to *technically* be an admin, yes. Is there any kind of backend security for requests? (Such as an edit, a verification to make sure that user really can edit)

Comment: @tymeJV yes, user will not be able to actually change anything on the server (although I am not writing the server code myself) but some things are considered security violation if a user can even see them (i.e list of all customers)

Comment: There's not much you can do if all you have to work with is client side security - anyone with enough determination can probably hack apart the view / client code.

Comment: @tymeJV Thanks. Good to know. Definitely a caveat to using ACL/rendering on client side which I was not aware of until now. Especially in situation where same page can show less/more data depending on ACL.

Comment: Yeah... it's a pain sometimes. As long as the server is locked down and verifying authentication you should be alright. User experience pretty much goes out the window if they're going to be messing with the console and trying to exploit weaknesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular way of hiding sections is with the `ng-if/ng-show/ng-hide` directives, as in:

```
<div ng-if="is_admin">...</div>
```

You can't hide those divs from people who look at the source, or the resources you make available in your app.  So don't provide admin data to those views.

My approach was to make an "admin" app in addition to the "standard" app and link between them.  This way, the only things exposed are links to the admin site, which are blocked to non-admin users:

```
<div ng-if="is_admin"><a href="/admin/#/link">Link</a></div>
```

All requests to my `/admin/*` pages return a 401 status code if they are not an admin.  The REST resources also return 401 status codes as appropriate.

(Edit: changed above `ng-hide` to `ng-if` to suppress those divs in the resulting DOM.)

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be a good solution for situations where there is a clear separation between the "basic" and the "admin" pages. However, what happens when some additional admin-features need to be displayed on the same page for example?

Comment: Then you run the risk of non-admin users being able to see it.

Comment: Can you use ng-if to suppress the div if user is not admin? My understanding is the HTML won't be visible in the source in that case.

Comment: @MikeTaverne, you are correct that `ng-if` will suppress the div, but it will still be in the raw source HTML.